# Why is current different in 2 identical parallel branches of my circuit?

Tags: current, basic

I'm trying to build the classic thermoregulated fans for an IT cabinet, and I'm struggling with some weird phenomenon. Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHT9tr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

+5V is provided by an arduino Uno, itself powered by a 12V supply. The 3rd pin of each sensor goes to the analog input of the arduino. There are 2 sensors because the cabinet will have multiples floors and I want to control the fans independantly of each other.

It works, but [datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1889026.pdf) for LM335AZ (thermal sensor) says that for maximum accuracy, current through the component should be around 1mA. Its voltage drop is 3V, so that's 2V in R1, with the 1kΩ resistor there should be 2mA, split in 2 that's 1mA for each branch.

However what I'm seeing is one branch takes 1.7mA and the other 0.3mA. As they are strictly identical I really don't understand why. My electrical basics are quite far, so what am I missing?

Comment: Why are they being used in parallel in the first place?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: I don't know, that seemed the way to go. Are disadvantages, aside the current imbalance?

Comment: Get a resistor for each diode.  They are not going to match exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are specifications on how much your sensors can vary.  They are clearly not identical, and one of them is stealing current from the other.  Just look at the tables in section 6 of the datasheet you link to, and now think about what happens when one sensor has a minimum value and one has a maximum value.

This is the same for many different circuit elements, and is why things like LED's each need their own current limiting resistor when arranged in parallel. As Matt points out below, every time you parallel diodes and transistors you need to be aware of this.

Comment: It's worth noting that any time you parallel up diodes or transistors, you need to be aware of this.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. So by removing the resistor and giving each sensor its own, current will be controlled, right?

Comment: @Antoine, yes.  The currents won't be IDENTICAL, but they will be within spec, especially after taking the variability between the resistors into account.

Answer (score 2):

> As they are strictly identical I really don't understand why.

Nope. Do this. Measure each diode's output when limited by a 2k resistor. You will find that the two have different voltages.

When you tie the two in parallel, the diode with the lower voltage will be the controlling diode, and the other one will draw less current at this lower voltage.